# How does Game and Watch's hammer work?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I remember reading that in the older games, you could not get the same number as either of the last two uses, but while I was playing on him on Super Smash Bros 4, (over multiple games) I got many repetitions of the same number, such as two 9's in a row and even three 4's in a row. Did they change the mechanic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSB4 removed the mechanic altogether, letting each independent use of the hammer roll between 1-9 randomly, so each number always has an ~11% chance of appearing.

More info on the move in the wiki [here.](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Judge)

And all changes to Game and Watch listed [here.](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Mr._Game_%26_Watch_%28SSB4%29)

Comment: Hmmm, so it seems like he is more luck based than ever now.

Comment: That would definitely seem to be the case. No more having to swing "dummy hammers". To be honest, I've stopped using the hammer altogether now, except as a joke. Rolling a 1 is just too costly.

Comment: Yeah, but rolling the 8 or 9 can win the whole game. I will probably use it less now, but i'll still use it.